# Razer Megalodon USB with Ubuntu 13.04 = disaster

Tags: 13.04, sound, usb, microphone

Here is my current setup : Asus G53SX + Logitech g500 mouse + Razer megalodon headset.

Here is my problem : If I for example want to listen to a song, the sound that comes out of the speakers sounds horrible, like the speaker is broken. I know for a fact that the headset is not broken since it works perfectly in Windows 7/8. But(!) when I change it from 7.1 to 4.1 it "crackling" disappears and the problem appears to go away, until I reboot ( it's still set to 4.1 when I've rebooted ) and the "crackling" starts again. If I then set it to 7.1 (still crackling) and then back to 4.1, the "crackling" goes away.

I've googled the shizzle out of my problem but I've not yet found a solution. I've tried all kinds of mixers/sound handling software and nothing appears to be working.

Minor note : the microphone is not working properly.

Thanks for taking your time and reading and hopefully helping me out. 
Regards, Victor.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the problem is related to pulse audio. I suggest you reading [this](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/paul/opensource/razer-megalodon-usb-headsets-and-fedora-or-ubuntu) where further info is provided, instructions of how to solve it are also there.

This might be related to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/658915) bug.

Comment: I've rolled this back to the initial version. You cannot just take the content from another website. The terms and conditions for Ask Ubuntu require that you own any content you post here.