# Awful sound quality in Razer Megalodon

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

I have a Razer Megalodon USB Headset that is producing extremely crackly sound in Ubuntu 13.04.

I've generated an alsainfo file to try to find out what the problem is, and it seems it's only recognizing one "PCM" channel. This is shown in alsamixer as well.

The alsainfo.txt file with most of the info I can get is here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48007253/alsa-info.txt.

The info given by `lsusb -v` is provided here (it gets important at line 990):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48007253/lsusb.txt

The output of `for i in $(find /proc/asound/); do echo $i:; cat $i; echo; done`, for those who are curious, is provided here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48007253/asound.txt

The output of `pacmd list` is provided here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48007253/pacmdlist.txt

I've confirmed the problem is not apparent in Windows 8.1, and it works with Plug-and-play functionality.

If I mess with the channel settings in the Ubuntu Sound Settings menu, I can occasionally get it working, but I can't get it to stay through reboots (or reconfiguring the sound menu again), and it definitely doesn't have the 7.1 surround sound.

Whether I use `aplay` or `mplayer` to test known good sound files, it doesn't produce discernible sound. Selecting any of the speakers in the Ubuntu Sound Settings menu does not produce *any* output. One thing to note is that the sound is *not* pure static. If I listen carefully, I can pick out occasional discernible syllables while running `mplayer Still\ Alive.mp3`.

Hopefully someone with some `usb-audio`/`ALSA`/`Pulseaudio` knowledge can help here.

(as a side note, it turns out it's a *bad idea* to install `oss4` on an Ubuntu system. Fortunately, I've got my sound back up and running again, now. It still didn't fix anything with the headset.)

Comment: This has already been answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/329756/razer-megalodon-usb-with-ubuntu-13-04-disaster/329758#329758

Comment: Notice how it's unnoticed and considered unanswered? That's because the answer given is completely useless.

Comment: Please show the output of `lsusb -v` (run as root) for this device.

Comment: Could you also provide the output of `pacmd list`?

Comment: I've added the output of `pacmd list` and some more info on the audio quality. If you need *any more* info, I can provide it. I'm also fine with getting my hands dirty with system files and the command line if needed. I just don't know the internals of the Linux usb stack or sound system very well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your headset has `7.1` channels.
Are you sure your laptop's sound card supports this many channels?

Make sure you have

```
default-sample-channels = 8
```

in

```
/etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

For more advanced configurations check [ALSA wiki](http://alsa.opensrc.org/SurroundSound)

Answer (score 0):

According to Razer:

Ensure that you are using the latest [firmware](http://drivers.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=105&pcid=37&nav=0,78,37&_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=105&pcid=37&nav=0,78,37) for your Megalodon.

Also try reseting the Razer Megalodon.  To reset the Razer Megalodon to factory default settings, press and hold the Channel Selector for 10 seconds while the Razer Megalodon is connected to a computer that is powered on.

**NOTE**:  ALL CONFIGURATION SETTINGS WILL BE LOST WHEN YOU RESET THE RAZER MEGALODON

Also, acoording to Dell, there have been [complaints about the Audio](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19367282.aspx) with the machine that you have.  As well as an urgent [BIOS update](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails/Product/studio-xps-1645?driverId=PDPD6&osCode=BIOSA&fileId=2731093177&languageCode=EN&categoryId=BI)

Comment: I have this BIOS update. Resetting was no use. It works in Windows no problem is the main thing.